# Numerical differentiation in Fortran

Tags: function, fortran

My code doesn't compile, I keep having the message 

`ta5p =(f(x+2.d0*h)-2.d0*f(x+h)+2.d0*f(x-h))/(2.d0*(h**3)) 
                                        1
Error: Function 'f' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type`
 and `Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)`

I need to create a program that computes the difference (`o(i) i = 1,n`) between the exact derivative and the numerical derivative. That was applied for some higher-order methods, that are indicated in my program as `s2p`,`t2p`, `s3p`, `s5p`, `ss3p`, `ss5p` and `ta5p`. The first, second and third derivative are defined as `df`, `d2f` and `d4f`, respectively. I tried to use functions in this so my loop remains organized, which made my program really big.

The input is a table "tab1_in.dat" that informs, on the first line, the number of different values `(n)` of `h`, a constant in numerical differentiation, and on second line, what are the values of `h`.

Here is the code

```
   program numerical differentiation
      implicit none
      integer i, n
      real*8 h(100), o(7)
      real*8, parameter :: x0 = 1.d0/3.d0 
      open(10,file = "tab1_in.dat")
      read(10,*)n        !receives the number of different values of h
      read(10,*) (h(i), i = 1,n)  !receive the values of h
      do i = 1,n
     !Calculates the deviation between the two types of differentiation

         o(1) = df(x0) - f2p(x0, h(k))
         o(2) = df(x0) - t2p(x0, h(k))
         o(3) = df(x0) - s3p(x0, h(k))
         o(4) = df(x0) - s5p(x0, h(k))
         o(5) = d2f(x0) - ss3p(x0, h(k))
         o(6) = d2f(x0) - ss5p(x0, h(k))
         o(7) = d3f(x0) - ta5p(x0, h(k))
         write(*,*) o(1),o(2),o(3),o(4),o(5),o(6),o(7)
      end do

      contains      
      real*8 Function f(x)  !the function that is being analyzed
      real*8 x
           f = (exp(4.d0*x))*(dcos(x/2.d0))
      end function f

      real*8 Function df(x) !first derivative of f(x)
      real*8 x
           df = (exp(4.d0*x))*(dcos(x/2.d0))
           df = 4.d0*df - (1.d0/2.d0)*(exp(4.d0*x))*dsin(x/2.d0)
      end function df

      real*8 Function d2f(x) !second derivative of f(x)
      real*8 x
           d2f = (exp(4.d0*x))*(dcos(x/2.d0))
           d2f = (63.d0/4.d0)*d2f - 4.d0*exp((4.d0*x))*dsin(x/2.d0)
      end function d3f

      real*8 Function d3f(x)    !third derivative of f(x)
      real*8 x
           d3f = 61.d0*(exp(4.d0*x))*[dcos(x/2.d0))
           d3f = d3f - (191.d0/8.d0)*(exp(4.d0*x))*dsin(x/2.d0)
      end function d3f
       !higher-order of numerical derivative
      real*8 Function f2p(x,h)
      real*8 x, h
           f2p = (f(x + h)/h) - (f(x)/h)
      end function f2p

      real*8 function t2p(x,h)
      real*8 x, h
           t2p = (f(x) - f(x - h))/h
      end function t2p

      real*8 function s3p(x,h)
     real*8 x, h
           s3p = (f(x + h) - f(x - h))/(2.d0*h)
      end function s3p

      real*8 function s5p(x,h)
      real*8 x,h
           s5p=(f(x+2.d0*h)-8.d0*f(x+h)+8.d0*f(x-h)-f(x2.d0*h))/(12.d0*h)
      end function s5p

      real*8 function ss3p(x,h)
      real*8 x,h
           ss3p = (f(x+h)-2.d0*f(x)+f(x-h))/(h**2.d0)
      end function ss3p

      real*8 function ss5p(x,h)
      real*8 x,h
           ss5p =(-f(x+2.d0*h)+16.d0*f(x+h)-30.d0*f(x))/(12.d0*(h**2.d0))
           ss5p = ss5p+(16.d0*f(x+h)-f(x-2.d0*h))/(12.d0*(h**2.d0))
      end function ss5p

      real*8 function ta5p(x,h)
      real*8 x,h
           ta5p =(f(x+2.d0*h)-2.d0*f(x+h)+2.d0*f(x-h))/(2.d0*(h**3))
           ta5p = ta5p + (-f(x-2.d0*h))/(2.d0*(h**3))
      end function ta5p
   end program numerical differentiation
```

Comment: What are you doing with those square brackets? You are multiplying length 1 arrays and assigning to a scalar, doesn't that throw an error?

Comment: I tried to fix it using the example as reference, I don't know how to simplify this program, and what square brackets?

Comment: these are square brackets: `[exp(4.d0*x)]` . You are makings arrays and a suppose that not your intent. You should just have one `contains` statement.

Comment: For clarity, the `[` and `]` characters in Fortran have a special meaning to declare arrays. `[1]` for instance is an integer array of length 1.

Comment: Also what a bizarre mix of styles! I really, really hope nobody is teaching you to use dsin and dcos  rather than sin (40 years obsolete), and it is very strange to see free format fortran with contains but use of the totally non-standard real*8 rather than kinds

Comment: My teacher told me to use dsin and dcos, the reason was to secure the double precision.

Comment: Your teacher was wrong. It has been the wrong way to do since 1977.

Comment: You should show the **complete** error message. It says *at (1)* but we cannot see here `(1)` points to, because you don't show the complete message.

Comment: So what is the right way to obtain the double precision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was using too much space in the horizontal direction of the editor vi, so it wasn't even showing the orange color that alerts to that problem.

The funny thing is that I made another code, but the results were different for those two. In my second code, I defined the exact derivative before the loop for x = 1/3, and then, within the loop I defined the numerical derivatives, also for x = 1/3, using only the function f(x) the same way that it it is written above. So there's something wrong with my logic that I need to figure it out. Anyway, thank you for your help.